# getView() with OnClickListener using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

Hope you are Fine.
I searched more about how to implement OnclickListener in getView() method, but this is still not implemented, I want to do an action with clicking a button located inside ListView.
Here is my Code.

```
public class Restaurant extends Activity {
private DatabaseHandler myDatabaseHandler;
ListView listContent;
Context context;
TextView rest_name;
TextView rest_hotline;
ImageButton call;
ImageView rest_image;
String image_string;
String r_n = "";
String r_e = "";
String r_h = "";
private CursorAdapter dataSource;
RelativeLayout resta;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant);
      listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.restaurants_list);
      call = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call);

      /*
       *  Create/Open a SQLite database
       *  and fill with dummy content
       *  and close it
       */
      myDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
      myDatabaseHandler.openToWrite();
      myDatabaseHandler.deleteAll();

      myDatabaseHandler.insert("First","1111",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
      myDatabaseHandler.insert("Second","0000",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
      myDatabaseHandler.close();

      /*
       *  Open the same SQLite database
       *  and read all it's content.
       */
      myDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
      myDatabaseHandler.openToRead();

      Cursor cursor = myDatabaseHandler.queueAll();
      startManagingCursor(cursor);
      String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_REST_NAME,DatabaseHandler.KEY_REST_HOTLINE, DatabaseHandler.KEY_REST_IMAGE};
      int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rest_name,R.id.rest_hotline, R.id.rest_image};

      final ListAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.lists, cursor, from, to);

      listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);   
      myDatabaseHandler.close();
}
private class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

     public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
       class ViewHolder {
         ImageButton b;
     }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               view = vi.inflate(R.layout.lists, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.b = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.call);
        view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {

            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ImageClickClick "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }
        });
        }
        return view;    
    }
```

XML files: Row of listview

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/restau" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/resta"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="#e74c3c">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/rest_image"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rest_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rest_image"
        android:text="ALL"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:typeface="sans"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rest_hotline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rest_image"
        android:text="Hotline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rest_name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:typeface="sans"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:focusable = "false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/stroke"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cat"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="#d93b2b">
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what error/result you have?

Comment: The ImageButton is not worked while clicking, cant do the action i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is B'coz you are not Using **CustomCursorAdapter**

You are using

```
final ListAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.lists, cursor, from, to);
```

and you have given **onClick** Action inside **CustomCursorAdapter**

```
holder.b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ImageClickClick "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }
        });
```

So you should use like

```
final CustomCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.lists, cursor, from, to);
```

Comment: @AnasSherif why are using SimpleCursorAdapter? Try using ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter. your CustomCursorAdapter implementation is incomplete.

Comment: Okay , Can you give me an example for using ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter.

Comment: @AnasSherif if it works for you, then don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: @AnasSherif go through this link. http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-alternate-list.html

Comment: Can't i use SimpleCursorAdapter?!? I knew that this is more faster while dealing the a database.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the else statment in getView methode

Answer (score 0):

I think miss alignment of code makes you trouble,Try this way...Hope it will work..

```
if(view == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.lists, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.b = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.call);
    view.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

}
holder.b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ImageClickClick "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
holder.b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ImageClickClick "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

                }

            }
        });
```

or implements CustomCursorAdapter

```
private class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements OnClickListener
```

and use

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ImageClickClicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
    }
```